# How to get Attributes & Claims (SSO - SAML) via MS graph API

Tags: azure, attributes, single-sign-on, claims

How can I get it via MS graph API?

[Attributes & Claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXP2U.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by calling graph API via access token. see the Microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Sorry, Which API do we use to get it? I can't find it anywhere, including a document from Microsoft.

Comment: have you looked into this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http? I also added it in the comment.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. My description isn't clear, so it makes you confused. I mean: I want to get a list of properties and the mapping names in config (I think it is mapping schema).